# How can I add horizontal, vertical RecyclerView inside a vertical scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I want to add vertical as well as horizontal RecyclerViews inside a vertical scrollview.

Is it possible to have multiple recycler views inside vertcal scrollview 
what control I need to use.

Also RecyclerView nested in one ScrollView is not good practice so can anybody tell me whats right way to do it can I add RecyclerView inside another RecyclerView or I need to use horizontal and vertical scrollview only to achieve this.

Comment: your question isn't very clear, can you explain what exactly you're trying to acheive here?

Comment: Its not a good idea to have scrollable view inside another scroll view. If you want so, you should set default height for recycler views.

Comment: I want to achieve something like google play homepage

Comment: use [NestedScrollView](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) instead of `ScrollView` and you can add `Horizontal RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this for getting two RecyclerView nested in one ScrollView which is by the way not recommended.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/old_map"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="none">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp">

            <view
            android:scrollbarSize="6dp"
            android:id="@+id/recent_post"
            class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

            <view
            android:scrollbarSize="6dp"
            android:id="@+id/recent_post"
            class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't namely know what kind of scrolling do you want but it is possible to use both scrolls at the same time:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <!-- HERE YOUR CODE-->
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I want to have horizontal lists inside scrollview

Comment: is it possible using recyler view